How to change encoding of directory in Visual Studio Code?
There is a similar question about it, but there is only a option for a single file or the whole workspace: Change the encoding of a file in Visual Studio Code
I have a project, which uses generated files in cp1252. But the rest of the project is utf8. I want to specify the directory of the generated files to be cp1252.

Keep UTF-8 Everywhere…

there's probably the option of rioV8's "command on all files" extension (I have no affiliation with this extension)
